# JFrame Eclipse 'add' command error

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, addition

While trying to add a button with "click me" written on it I get the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:  Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   add(Component) from the type Container

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class FirstFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My little frame");
        JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
        add(button);
        frame.setSize(300,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Any help to resolve this error would be much appreciated!

Comment: From the computer's point of view, it doesn't know what you are trying to `add` to.  Presumably it's the JFrame called `frame` that you're trying to add to, so the code should be `frame.add(button);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The add() method is an instance method, and can only be called on an instance of (in this case) frame.

try

```
frame.add(button);
```

Comment: The proper way to add a component to a JFrame is to add it on its contentPane. So, frame.getContentPane().add(button)

Comment: @GeorgeZougianos, since jdk 5 (I think) if you add a component to the frame it will add the component to the content pane of the frame. That is the add() is forwarded to the content pane as a convenience method. There is no need to use getContentPane() first.

Comment: @George Zougianos, I am not familiar with the details of this class.... I was just commenting on the instance/class scope of the method so I defer to your knowledge.  I only add this comment so the original asker is not mislead by my answer.